# How do I check if a number of values are beside each other in a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

These are my codes currently:

```
points = 0
#where points is 1 per individual HWY connected to each other

map1 = [ ['HWY', 'HWY', 'HWY', 'FAC'],
         ['HWY', 'HWY', '   ', 'SHP'],
         ['   ', 'HSE', 'HSE', 'FAC'],
         ['HWY', 'BCH', 'HSE', 'HSE'] ]
```

Points in this case can be changed based on number of `HWY` in each row, so if row one has 3 `HWY`, the points will be 3 + 3 + 3 for row one alone.

This are my current code:

```
map1 = [ ['HWY', 'HWY', 'HWY', 'HWY'],
         ['HWY', 'HWY', 'SHP', 'SHP'],
         ['   ', 'HSE', 'HSE', 'FAC'],
         ['HWY', 'BCH', 'HSE', 'HSE'] ]

SHP_pos = [(idx, i) for idx, sublist in enumerate(map1) for i, v in enumerate(sublist) if v == 'HWY']
count_list1 = []
count_list2 = []
count_list3 = []
count_list4 = []

for x in SHP_pos:
     if x[0] == 0:
          count1 = x[1]
          count_list1.append(count1)

     if x[0] == 1:
          count2 = x[1]
          count_list2.append(count2)

     if x[0] == 2:
          count3 = x[1]
          count_list3.append(count3)

     if x[0] == 3:
          count4 = x[1]
          count_list4.append(count4)

print(count_list1, count_list2, count_list3, count_list4)

print(SHP_pos)
```

After this, I was planning to just do `count = len(count_list1) ** len(count_list1) + len(count_list2) ** len(count_list2) + len(count_list3) ** len(count_list3) + len(count_list4) ** len(count_list4)`.

The issue with my code is that it does not check if `HWY` is beside each other, for example if `map1[ [ 'HWY', 'HWY', 'FAC', 'HWY']...` for row 1, it will still show up as `count_list1 = [0, 1, 3]`, and when I use `len()` for that the answer would be wrong, as supposed points should be : 2 + 2 + 1 for row 1.

Comment: What's your expected output

Comment: points = 2 (basically `map1[0][1] and map1[0][2]`). just added it into the code

Comment: `map1[0][1]` and `map1[1][1]` are also considered next to each other?

Comment: nope. Horizontal only; so esseitially only if they are in the same row `map1[0]`, `map1[1]`... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the question was edited to include more than two adjacent values:

You can build a list of lists the hold sequences based on the indices of the searched value in each row

```
def group_sequence(lst):
    if not lst:
        return []

    res = [[lst[0]]]
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        if lst[i - 1] + 1 == lst[i]:
            res[-1].append(lst[i])
        else:
            res.append([lst[i]])
    return res


map1 = [['HWY', 'HWY', 'HWY', 'FAC'],
        ['HWY', 'HWY', '   ', 'SHP'],
        ['   ', 'HSE', 'HSE', 'FAC'],
        ['HWY', 'BCH', 'HSE', 'HSE']]

map2 = [['HWY', 'HWY', 'HWY', 'HWY'],
        ['HWY', 'HWY', 'SHP', 'SHP'],
        ['   ', 'HSE', 'HSE', 'FAC'],
        ['HWY', 'BCH', 'HSE', 'HSE']]

target = 'HWY'

# map1
points = sum(len(group) for row in map1 for group in group_sequence([i for i, x in enumerate(row) if x == target])
             if len(group) > 1)
print(points) # 5

# map2
points = sum(len(group) for row in map2 for group in group_sequence([i for i, x in enumerate(row) if x == target])
             if len(group) > 1)
print(points) # 6
```

Original, in case you have max of two adjacent values:

You can iterate over each item in each row and check if the current item is the same as the next and equal to `HWY`

```
target = 'HWY'
points = 0
for row in map1:
    for i in range(len(row) - 1):
        if row[i] == target and row[i] == row[i + 1]:
            points += 2
print(points)
```

Or with generator expression

```
points = sum(2 for row in map1 for i in range(len(row) - 1) if row[i] == target and row[i] == row[i + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `for` loop:

```
points = 0
for sublist in map1:
    l = [i for i, v in enumerate(sublist) if v == 'HWY']
    for val in [y - x for x, y in zip(l, l[1:])]:
        if val == 1:
            points += 2
print(points)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Counting up any two adiacent matching values:
points = 0
for left, right in zip(values[:-1], values[1:]):
    if left == right:
        points += 1

# Or getting everything together
points = 0
for row in matrix:
    for left, right in zip(values[:-1], values[1:]):
        if left == right:
            points += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

for the following map:

```py
map1 = [ ['HWY', 'HWY', 'HWY', 'FAC'],
         ['HWY', 'HWY', '   ', 'SHP'],
         ['   ', 'HSE', 'HSE', 'FAC'],
         ['HWY', 'BCH', 'HSE', 'HSE'] ]
```

The map can be described as a binary matrix

1. for each occurance of "HWY" map to `1` else map to `0`

```py
[ [ 1, 1, 1, 0 ],
  [ 1, 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

2. for each row encode to decimal

```
[ 14, 12, 0, 8 ]
```

Now we can easily identify our target pattern using the following table:

| Binary | Decimal | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1100 | 12 | 2 |
| 0110 | 6 | 2 |
| 0011 | 3 | 2 |
| 1110 | 14 | 3 |
| 0111 | 7 | 3 |
| 1111 | 15 | 4 |

> The above table uses static values and maps the points worth for each decimal number, by mapping to `2` if decimal in `[3,6,12]` and to `3` if in `[7,14]` and `4` if equal to `15` else `0`.

Following the table we can [14,12,0,8] → [3,2,0,0].

Finally we sum array numbers, and that would be our points:

```
points = 3 + 2 + 0 + 0 = 5
```

Here is the code:

```py
points = sum(2 if e in [3,6,12] else 3 if e in [7,14] else 4 if e == 15 else 0 for e in [int("".join(["1" if "HWY" == e else "0" for e in row]),2) for row in map1])
```